# Using coldfusion pages in dotNetNuke

Tags: coldfusion, dotnetnuke

We need to incorporate coldfusion pages into a DotNetNuke site. Example, a login page, consisting of a simple login form. OnSubmit, a coldfusion cfc webservice is called to check the credentials, returning a success flag. I am brand new to DotNetNuke and don't even know if this can be accomplished. Googling reveals next to nothing, which probably isn't a good sign. If anyone can provide a real simple example of how to do this, I would be extremely grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be to use the IFrame module in DotNetNuke, if you don't have the IFrame module available check out the Host/Extensions page, and click on the Available Extensions option.

Your cold fusion pages will have to reside somewhere else, but within the IFrame they can be loaded into a DotNetNuke website.

Long term you would likely be served best by rewriting that functionality inside of a DotNetNuke module, or finding a module that provides the same functionality.

Comment: Yep, the iframe way is a breeze